# Codeigniter: Pagination, 2 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've been working to resolve this issue for some time but it's not working out.
The second page displays 404 error. Would appreciate if someone could find time to review the code. I've also worked on the route, but it still displays 404 error on the 2 page.
Here's the 
**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Products_model');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

public function index($offset = 0) {
        //how many blogs will be shown in a page
        $limit = 3;
        $result = $this->Products_model->get_blogs($limit, $offset);
        $data['blog_list'] = $result['rows'];
        $data['num_results'] = $result['num_rows'];
        // load pagination library
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/nwpgroup/nwp2/index.php';
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_results'];
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        //which uri segment indicates pagination number
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        //max links on a page will be shown
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
        //various pagination configuration
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<span class="first">';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['first_link'] = '';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<span class="last">';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['last_link'] = '';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<span class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<span class="next">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $config['next_link'] = '';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('products', $data);
    }
```

Model part

```
public $products = 'products';


     public function get_blogs($limit, $offset) {
            if ($offset > 0) {
                $offset = ($offset - 1) * $limit;
            }
            $result['rows'] = $this->db->get($this->products, $limit, $offset);
            $result['num_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results($this->products);
            return $result;
        }
```

View.

```
<?php
        foreach ($blog_list->result() as $blog) {
            ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title"><?php echo $blog->id; ?></h2>
                <p class="meta">
                    <?php
                    echo $blog->name;
                    ?>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p><?php echo $blog->price; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        if (strlen($pagination)) {
            echo $pagination;
        }
    ?>
```

Thanks for taking your time to review this code.

Comment: Show you full controller

Comment: @B.Desai, I've updated the controller

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: Controller name is **Products**

Comment: What is the url of first page? is it `http://localhost/nwpgroup/products /` or some thing else?

Comment: The url of the first page is http://localhost/nwpgroup/nwp2/index.php/products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue in `base_url` for pagination

change

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/nwpgroup/nwp2/index.php';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/nwpgroup/nwp2/index.php/products/index/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Base url in pagination is pointing your controller function in which data is being fetched from model.

so you have to set base_url as

```
 $config['base_url'] = site_url("products/index/");
```

`site_url` will return your project url with `index.php`.